# Mysql: Update field of most latest record

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm trying to update the latest record where name is `John` (`John` has multiple records but different ID) but I seem to be in a bind. What's wrong with my query?

```
UPDATE messages_tbl SET is_unread=1
WHERE ReceiveTime = (SELECT MAX(ReceiveTime) FROM messages_tbl WHERE name='John')
```

Is there a better way to do something like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can join both and perform update based on the condition.

```
UPDATE  messages a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  name , MAX(ReceiveTime) max_time
            FROM    messages 
            GROUP   BY name 
        ) b ON  a.name = b.name AND
                a.ReceiveTime = b.max_time
SET     a.is_unread = 1
-- WHERE    a.name = 'John'
```

Without the `WHERE` condition. It will all update the column `is_unread` for the latest entry.

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting an `Error Code : 1064`.

Comment: `Query : update messages s1 set is_unread=1  inner join (SELECT Name, MAX(ReceiveTime) max_time FROM messages group by Messa...
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join (SELECT Name, MAX(ReceiveTime) max_time FROM messages group' at line 2`

Comment: Brilliant! Do you mind explaining why the other one didn't work? I uncommented the `WHERE` so I can target specific rows and it still worked. :)

Comment: @enchance which other one?

Comment: The first code before you edited it and came up with this one.

Comment: Oh, it was really a synrax error because the SET statement was brfore the INNER JOIN keyword.

Answer (score 74):

You could try using [`ORDER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) and `LIMIT`.

Try this:

```
UPDATE messages_tbl SET is_unread = 1
WHERE name = 'John'
ORDER BY ReceiveTime DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This query will update the rows in order of the highest (most recent) `ReceiveTime` to the lowest (oldest) `ReceiveTime`. Used in conjunction with `LIMIT`, only the most recent `ReceiveTime` will be altered.

Comment: @enchance - Not a problem, just wanted to make sure my answer was still relevant to your question :).