# Update only last record in laravel table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to get the last record from the colume, then update it...just the last record

i have tried like this but its not working

```php
DB::table('sales')
    ->where('id', $salesid)
    ->pluck('debt')
    ->last()
    ->update([
        'debt'. => 34
    ]);
```

Comment: yes i can find the last record...but how do i update the last record?

Comment: it doesn't have to be 2 queries, it can be done in a single query.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715922/mysql-update-field-of-most-latest-record

Comment: Try this : `$last_row = DB::table('sales')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();` then `$update = DB::table('sales')->where('id', $last_row->id)->update(['debt' => 34]);`

Comment: the last record? i would assume an 'id' is a unique identifier so there shouldn't be more than 1 of those ... are you saying the field named `debt` has many values? not understanding why 'last' or 'first' etc is in play here

Comment: Doesn't need to be 2 queries; just use a `limit()`: `DB::table('sales')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->limit(1)->update(['debt' => 34]);`. But, as stated, the `orderBy()` and `limit()` seem redundant if `id` is being provided, since it should be unique. If it isn't, that's a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it many ways

```
$your_data=Model::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
$your_data->update(['column' => "value"]);
```

or you can use

```
$your_data=Model::latest()->first();
```

then update

```
$your_data->update(['column' => "value"]);
```

Comment: i need the last record not the first

Comment: latest()->first() return you the last record

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are concerning about performance, you should use direct update to the DB with out selecting from DB which add a extra overhead, This will work for `mysql`

```
 $updated = Model::orderBy('id', 'DESC')
     ->limit(1)
     ->update([
         "debt" => 34
     ]);
```

or else

```
DB::table('sales')
->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
->limit(1)
->update([
    'debt' => 34
])
```